# Chinese characters showing up as boxes in dreamweaver

Tags: special-characters, dreamweaver, html-escape-characters

When trying to copy paste some Chinese characters in a HTML file open in Dreamweaver I see that its being represented as boxes. When I view the pave on a browser I can see the characters correctly so its just in Dreameaver that they don't show up.

I read some posts on S.O. about utf-8 and saving with BOM disabled.I have even included Chinese on my keyboard with no luck.
edit. I tried editing the Fonts in Edit>Preferences to Chinese but when I click OK and I go back to it it shows Unicode again.

I could just copy and paste everything and it will work but it would be easier if I can see the different characters so when I need to hyperlink some word or include it in a  tag I dont have to count boxes and view on the browser to figure it out.

Comment: Does the font selected for Dreamweaver have *glyphs* for those characters? Because that's what those boxes indicate: Valid character encoding, but no corresponding glyph in the font. (At least in the apps I am using, not sure about Dreamweaver which I don't use.)

Comment: I dont know if glyph are the same as font in Dreamweaver. I tried editing the Fonts in Edit>Preferences to Chinese but when I click OK and I go back to it it shows Unicode again.

Comment: Err... I think we have a disconnect in terminology here. A *glyph* is the actual graphical representation in your selected font (e.g. "A") of a *character* (e.g. "LATIN CAPITAL LETTER A") which is represented by one or more *code points* (e.g. U+0041) which is given in a specific *encoding* (e.g. 0x41 for UTF-8, 0x0041 for UTF-16). "Unicode" is the agreement on character "names", code points, and encodings, but doesn't say anything about fonts and glyphs. Those "boxes" you see usually indicate that the font used by the application does not have a glyph for the given character.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out what was the problem. It was an encoding issue on Dreamweaver.

Went to Modify>Page Properties>Title/Encoding and changed the encoding to Chinese.
The Unicode showed up boxes in Dreamweaver.

However if you have already text copied in then they might not turn to the actual characters correctly so you have to re-enter them or if you didn't enter anything text yet its ok.